# calculating sums for dynamically added form elements

Tags: php, ajax, javascript

I have below form, where each `.form-row` is dynamically added using jQuery when user clicks on Add New button.

**My html form (simplified)**

```
<div id="total_sum">
  <!-- here will show up total amount, which is sum of unit[] * price[] - discount[] of all below form-rows -->
</div>

<div id="total_discount">
  <!-- here will show up total discount amount, which is sum of discount[] of all below form-rows -->
</div>

<div id="total_net">
  <!-- here will show up net amount, which is total_sum - total_discount -->
</div>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="">

  <div class="form-row">
    <select name="item[]">
      <option value="item-id-1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="item-id-2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="item-id-3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" class="unit" value="1" name="unit[]" />
    <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" />
    <input type="number" class="discount" name="discount[]" />
    <input type="number" class=name="sum[]" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <select name="item[]">
      <option value="item-id-1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="item-id-2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="item-id-3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" class="unit" value="1" name="unit[]" />
    <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" />
    <input type="number" class="discount" name="discount[]" />
    <input type="number" class="sum" name="sum[]" />
  </div>

  <!-- and users can dynamically add as many form-rows as they want -->

  <div class="form-row">
    <select name="item[]">
      <option value="item-id-1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="item-id-2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="item-id-3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" class="unit" value="1" name="unit[]" />
    <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" />
    <input type="number" class="discount" name="discount[]" />
    <input type="number" class="sum" name="sum[]" />
  </div>

</form>
```

And what I am trying to achieve is two-folded:

- calculate the sum of each line (`.form-row`) and display the sum in each line (in `sum[]` field)
- calculate the sum of all sums and discounts of all lines (all `.form-row`s) and display them in `#total_sum`, `#total_discount`, and `#total_net`.

I believe I need something that gets all `.form-row`s, which is triggered whenever there is a change in the form (or every 1 second, perhaps?), and loop through them to calculate respective sum, and calculate the total of sums and discounts when looping is over. I can do this if it's PHP, but I am quite new to jQuery or Javascript so I have no idea where to look into first.

[Adddd]

One thing I did not mention in above explanation is that unit[] has default value of 1 and price[] is at first automatically appended using AJAX, and then users can change the value.

**My AJAX to automatically retrieve price when user selects an item.**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /*  Get Item Price and Item Currency */
    $('#form').on('change', '.item_id', function(){
        var this$ = $(this);
        var $item_id    =  this$.val();

        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

        // call ajax for item price (returns 0 if item has no price)
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data:' action=get_item_price_by_id&item_id='+$item_id,
            type:'GET',
            success:function(results) {
                this$.parent().parent().find('.price').empty();
                this$.parent().parent().find('.price').val(results);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks to the advice from Manish Jangir Blogadditic, I came to have below code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Calculate sub-sums on any form changes
    $("#form").change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.form-row').each(function() {
          sum = Number( $(this).find('unit').val()) * Number( $(this).find('price').val() );
          alert( sum );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

However, it works when the form is manually changed, but doesn't work when price is automatically appended by ajax.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you seeing the value filled in .price element?

Comment: Yes, value is properly filled in .price element when I select an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button #form comes with the last added dynamic element then you can try this out because .change or .on don't work with dynamically appended html elements. jQuery has given a $(document).on event to do that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Calculate sub-sums on any form changes
    $(document).on('click','#form',function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.form-row').each(function() {
          sum += Number( $(this).find('.unit').val()) * Number( $(this).find('.price').val() );
          alert( sum );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Manish Jangir Blogadditic, but I have something I didn't explain in the question and just added it. The problem is that your code works when I manually change the values in .unit or .price, but doesn't work when .unit and .price are automatically appended by AJAX (.unit and .price are automatically appended when user selects an item). Any other advice?

Comment: where is  $("#form") in your code ? Does it come with the last added div?

Comment: Tried `$(document).on('change','#form',function()`, `$(document).on('click','#form',function()`, `$("body").on('change','#form',function()`, and `$("body").on('click','#form',function()` but all are resulting the same: works for manual changes, but doesn't work for AJAX-triggered changes.

Comment: I ended up using $(document).on('blur', '#form', function(). Anyways, users will *blur* the form at least once if they are to submit the form. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a delegated event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Calculate sub-sums on any form changes
    $("#form").on('change','.price, .unit',function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.form-row').each(function() {
          sum = Number( $(this).find('.unit').val()) * Number( $(this).find('.price').val() );
          alert( sum );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Moreover, sum should be calculated either when .price is changed or when .unit is changed.

Comment: Thanks again, but giving both .price and .unit didn't work, either.

Comment: you need to parseInt all the value like that way.
parseInt($(this).find('.unit').val())

Answer (score 0):

Value changed by Javascript will not trigger onchange event. And this rule applied on JQuery's change function too. So you may need to manually trigger onchange event after the updating. With Jquery you may use .trigger(), check here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will resolve your issue.

> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function() {
> // Calculate sub-sums on any form changes
>     $("#form").on('change',function() {
>         var sum = 0;
>         $('.form-row').each(function() {
>           sum +=  parseInt($(this).find('.unit').val()) +  parseInt($(this).find('.price').val());
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```